# Xubuntu 16.04: Monitor going to standby then back on again at start-up

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, display, radeon, monitor

After selecting my Xubuntu 16.04 partition from the Grub menu, my monitor goes into standby, stating "No signal", then shortly after comes back on again and Xubuntu loads as normal. It does not seem to take any extra time, taking about the same time to load as older releases took, but it is certainly very odd and I would like to know what is causing it. My GPU is an AMD HD7750 using the radeon driver and I'm using an AOC monitor.

I recorded a short video of this with my phone, you can see the monitor light go orange and the "No Signal" message: https://vid.me/YOqO

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing unusual. Most, if not all computers have this. The computer or OS just stops putting out a signal temporarily. I think it's what happens when the bootloader loads the OS, but I'm not sure.

However, **it's completely normal**.

It's happened in every computer I've used. Don't worry about it.